# Safari not displaying SVG in the right position

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari

I want to create some image placeholders that stay for 1 second and then fade out displaying the image. I am using SVGs that I generate by reading the image width and height.

The images (and SVGs) are responsive, adapting to the container size.

I want to also randomly place the images on four potential different places within the container: right, left (for portrait) and top, bottom (for landscape).

The SVGs are placed right on top of the images on Chrome, while on Safari the  inside of the SVG is always centered.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.continer svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.container svg rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container position-top">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 63.863757317722 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="1200" height="1879"></rect>
  </svg>
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/bbbellon/pen/PoxYQpP

Comment: Does adding actual positioning values fix this issue? Not sure if safari doe sthe 'absolute' thing if you don't.

Comment: Hi @somethinghere, I just added top: 0 and left: 0 to the SVG but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: First thing: your `svg` selector is missing a letter: `.contAiner`. Also, this is probably due to the default behaviour of SVG elements being stretched. Also, you are not forcing you SVG to stretch, just not to scale up.

Comment: Hi, that was actually an error while writing the code in here. But I created a reproduction on Codepen. https://codepen.io/bbbellon/pen/PoxYQpP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `.container svg` you need to switch

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

to be

```
width: auto;
height: 100%;
```

Setting a `max-height` and / or `max-width` is not a problem but it does not tell the `<svg>` what size you actually want it to be. If you use dev tools you'll see, with your original code, the `<svg>` takes up the whole `.container` and the `<rect>` sits centrally within that. The placement of the `<rect>` within the `<svg>` is expected behaviour. If you tell the `<svg>` to take up 100% of its parent's height and then set the width to `auto` the `viewBox` attribute will manage the scaling of the `<svg>` on your behalf.

As a side note, you do not need the following on `.container svg rect`

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right! I just need to switched the "100%" and "auto" depending on the image aspect ratio if landscape or portrait and it works perfect!